# Error receiving Long Shadow documents in AWS IOT core (MQTT)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am using AWS-IOT embedded C sdk for MQTT communication.

I am able to receive small messages from a named shadow, but when the shadow document is big and lots of fields, my application fails.? Mqtt has a limit of 128KB but shadow document is 1KB (Shadow has a limit of 8 KB).
I am using shadowprefix/get/accepted to receive the document.

Comment: As you say your issue is unlikely to be MQTT protocol related (an 8kb message is fine). Significantly more information will be needed in order to provide assistance e.g. how does your application fail (errors etc), source code (ideally a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), device information (on a unit with 32KB RAM an 8KB message is fairly big!).

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the network buffer size solved the issue.